# Unable to commit files. Maven

Tags: java, maven

I've problem with release:prepare in Maven. When I enter "mvn release:prepare" I get error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project com.joledzki.petclinic2: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-commit command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

pom.xml

```
 <scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:JakubOledzki/petclinic2.git</developerConnection>
  <tag>com.joledzki.petclinic2-0.0.2</tag>
```

Build work correct. Someone has a solution ?

Comment: Is the user running the maven command allowed to commit to the repo and branch?

Comment: How is spring-boot-maven-plugin related to the question? (It appears in the name of the question). Does mvn release:prepare work when you comment out the spring-boot-maven-plugin?

Comment: @Nicktar Yes, its main account where is the repo.

Comment: @MarkBramnik My bad :( Already edited. I made it too fast :)

Comment: Have you tried `[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.`?

Comment: Yes, its same. I created new SSH key but still doesn't work

Comment: @Olus - You should mention the repo URL which means either ssh or https should be there. THis is the syntax - <service name>:<scm implementation>:<repository url>. Example - scm:svn:http://somerepository.com/svn_repo/trunk. For more info https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html